# django what variable in filter

Tags: django, django-views

Complex model:

```
Class Name(models.Model):
  first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
  middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
 last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)

class Person(models.Model):
  names = models.ManyToManyField('Name')
  wives = models.ManyToManyField('Person',related_name='husbands',null = True, blank = True)
```

And Form:

```
class PersonForm(ModelForm):
  names_list = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Name.objects.filter(person=2), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={"checked":""}))
  wives_list = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Person.objects.filter(husbands=2), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={"checked":""}))

     class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('names','wives')
        widgets = {
         'names' : forms.HiddenInput(),
         'wives': forms.HiddenInput(),
        }
```

This is hardcoded for Person number 2 (person=2, husbands=2).

And it works. But now, I want to change number 2 into variable which is related to current edited person.

If I look at html source - I can see the hidden fields:

```
<input id="id_names" name="names" type="hidden" value="[30, 63]" />

<input id="id_wives" name="wives" type="hidden" value="[42]" />
```

So - there's two ways:

`Name.objects.filter(person=somevariable)` - shows the names of person number

or

`Name.objects.fiter(id__in=othervariable)` - shows the values in names variable

(the same with wives)

But nothing works - especially - I can't find the proper variable - i'm so close....

Answer (score 0):

I found the main mistake - I can't set the id in the class, because it is not set yet. It is set in `__init__` constructor. So I have to change it into:

```
class PersonForm(ModelForm):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(PersonForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    instance = getattr(self, 'instance', None)
    if instance and instance.pk:
      self.fields['names_list'].queryset=Name.objects.filter(person=instance.pk)
      self.fields['wives_list'].queryset=Person.objects.filter(husbands=instance.pk)

  names_list = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Name.objects.none(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={"checked":""}))
  wives_list = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Person.objects.none(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={"checked":""}))

     class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('names','wives')
        widgets = {
         'names' : forms.HiddenInput(),
         'wives': forms.HiddenInput(),
        }
```

If someone finds a better solution - I would be appreciated.